# tell moquitto server/broker to retain certain topics?

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

Some IoT devices are sending me messages concerning their power switches which I would like to 'retain', in order to allow new MQTT connections to immediately know if the other device is turned on or off. Sadly, the IoT device doesn't set the 'retain' option on these topics, so I have to wait til their next periodic call-in to ascertain their current status.

Is there a way to tell de mosquitto server/broker to retain certain incoming messages, or do only the clients have that option?

A workaround would be to have a constant process re-publish the messages with the retain option set, but that seems like a kludge.

Comment: That is the kludge you need.

Comment: No, the right way to fix this is to fix the IoT devices.

Comment: Have you had a look in to the [HiveMQ Community Edition](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-community-edition)?
It's open source and  comes with an open source [Extension SDK](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-extension-sdk), which you could utilise to intercept incoming PUBLISH and change the retained flag.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but developing a plugin, in Java (im more of a perl guy) seems a bit overkill.
I settled on querying they relay's status over MQTT and immediately listening for a response (takes maybe a second). Would still be a nice feature, though.